# Updating Prices table on a button click in PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Iam doing an application. I need to update Prices table on a button click. I have 2 tables, one is "Currency" table and another is "Price" table.The db structure is as follows:

```
Currency Table
______________

id | currency | rate
_____________________
1    USD         1
2    INR         66.7
3    GBP         0.66264

Price Table
____________

id | Currency | Total | UpdatedPrice
____________________________________
1    USD        300      89898
1    INR        500      500
1    USD        6000     87878787
1    GBP        6777     9887
2    USD        89       4567
2    INR        34       7676
3    USD        878      8889
```

The scenario is on a button click i need to update the Price table. The latest prices are downloaded to the currency table. There are some formulaes involved.
The system should check the currency value from the price table. The formulae is

```
IF (INR) 
 Just show the total field
IF USD
  total * rate (it should take from the currency table)
IF GBP
  rate(INR Rate Currency Table)/GBP Rate (Currency Table)
```

And the system should update the Price (Updated Price) field. I just wanted to know how to approach this.

Is this query fine?

```
UPDATE comparitive_st_sup fc
    JOIN currency1 fer ON fc.tender_id = $tender_id
SET fc.total_inr = (CASE 
    WHEN fc.currency = 'INR' THEN fc.total
    WHEN fc.currency = 'USD' THEN ((fc.total / fer.rate) * 66.678609)
    WHEN fc.currency = 'GBP' THEN ((fc.total / fer.rate) * 66.678609)
    END)
```

Comment: Are you asking someone to write down an application for you? Start coding then ask the questions here about the issues you faced while implementing.

Comment: You can simplify that down (always) to `(Total / item rate) * INR rate` Once you've simplifed it, building the single query should be relatively simple

Comment: @ Babak T. I just asked how to approach it. I dont want you to write any solution for me. Thank you for your time

Comment: @RowlandShaw, i have updated the question. I have added a query. I would like to know your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To answer on how to APPROACH it you can start with this:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'mysql', 'db_name');
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        /*
         * SELECT ACTIONS FROM ONE TABLE
         */

        /*
         * CALCULATIONS
         */

        /*
         * UPDATE ACTIONS TO ANOTHER TABLE
         */


    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: i have updated the question. I have added a query. I would like to know your suggestion.